# Why am I getting an error about placement new when I'm not using placement new?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator, placement-new

I'm getting this error:

```
error: exception cleanup for this placement new selects non-placement operator delete [-fpermissive]
    ptrCpMsgHandler = new cpMsgHandler;
```

Isn't this just a plain old 'new'? Here's more of the code:

```
bool someCondition = true;
cpMsgHandler *ptrCpMsgHandler;
ptrCpMsgHandler = new cpMsgHandler;
if(someCondition)
{
    delete ptrCpMsgHandler;
}
```

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: Why the separate declaration and initialization of the pointer?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/c8fd8ovxr)

Comment: Note that if you are using MSVC's MFC library and doing a debug build it is very likely that new has been #defined (even though this is not technically legal per the standard). Uses of "new" in the code stream look perfectly ordinary but in fact are passed arguments.

Comment: Does the class have a new operator? Or did you overload the global new?

Comment: 12 hours without more info. It needs a [mre].